# Font awesome with raphael js

Tags: raphael, font-awesome

What I want is to create a simple circle with [raphaeljs](http://raphaeljs.com/) that will have the facebook's 'f' inside (this will also be used for other similar cases). The 'f' symbol will be produced by [font-awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/).

What I have done (and did not work) is to set the font family using css and/or as a raphael attribute.

The code is the following:

### HTML

```
<div id='share-facebook'></div>
```

### CSS

```
#share-facebook {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

### Javascript

```
var canvas = Raphael('share-facebook', 100, 100);
var facebookWrapper = canvas.circle(50,50,50);
facebookWrapper.attr('fill', '#E3E3E3');
facebookWrapper.attr('stroke','none');
var facebookText = canvas.text(50,50,'&#xf09a');
facebookText.attr('font-size', 40);
facebookText.attr('fill', '#fff');
facebookText.attr('font-family','FontAwesome');
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/gkaran/K6rrf/) is also a fiddle to make your life easier. From what I have seen the issue is that raphaels places the character inside a tspan inside the text node and it cannot be decoded. Anyone has an idea how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `canvas.text(50,50,'\uf09a');` instead of `canvas.text(50,50,'&#xf09a');` and it works

Answer (score 0):

Not really the answer you expect, but you can use Raphael free icons (http://raphaeljs.com/icons/) instead of FontAwesome. Each icon is a Raphael path you can then do:

```
paper.path(<icon path here>).attr({fill: "#000", stroke: "none"});
```

then I guess you can apply any transform, scaling, positionning as with any other path.

I did a little update on your fiddle to demonstrate http://jsfiddle.net/K6rrf/1/. I did not remove your code just added the 2 last lines...

Hope this helps a bit

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for that. I am already familiar with raphael and I use it in the same project but I wanted to take advantage of FontAwesome in this one. If no other option exists then, this is going to be my final resort.